# How to properly pass content from a local page to an include page in php

Tags: php

includepage.php

```
<?php
echo $variable;
?>
```

localpage.php

```
<?php 
$variable = 'Content';
include 'includepage.php';
?>
```

How do I properly have a local page give a variable to an include. I was thinking classes, and I tried to instantiate it but couldn't get it to work in my specific circumstances. I have a page that is a template of content for all pages and the $variable is the content specific to each local page. What I listed above works but it's not good practice I'm told.

Comment: This used be a real problem, when `register_globals` was still a thing (decades ago). But even today you should think about what happens when somebody calls `includepage.php` directly. The error messages might leak information you don't want to share.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know why it's a bad practice. I could make it work with sessions too but that also isn't ideal.

Comment: Don't do that. You have two good answers on how to do it properly. If you need a quick fix against direct calls, you can just define a constant in your local pages and check if its defined in the include page. Wordpress et al. live with that band-aid for years.

Answer (score 1):

You should never have code in an include file which is invoked at the time the code is included. Your include file should only contain constant, class and function definitions. The code is then:

- more predictable
- easier to reuse
- less likely to expose backdoors to your application

Of course, as with every rule there are exceptions, but the only one I can think of which has any merit in this context is when you are using an auto-prepend include to modify the behaviour of the environment while deliberately not modifying the application code (e.g. using a custom session handler with an off-the-shelf application).

You seem to be describing a front controller pattern - where requests for different functionality are first routed to the same php script. The term "templating" is typically applied to the opposite of this architecture - where the page layout for multiple seperate php scripts is handled by a common include file.

> I tried to instantiate it but couldn't get it to work in my specific circumstances

Try again. You're never going to be able to build an application of any complexity without functions or classes.

Answer (score 0):

tehpage.php

```
<?php
class tehpage {
    public function __construct($parameters = null) {
        //i.e. the parameters may determine which content is shown
        $this->content = "page content";
    }
    public function htmlOut() {
        echo $this->content;
    }
}
?>
```

actualpage.php

```
<?php
include "tehpage.php";
$page = new tehpage($variousparametersyoulikeIlikearrays);
$page->htmlOut();
?>
```

Like so ?

Comment: I can do a simple function/class. My issue was when I tried to implement it into my template page within the given div. The pages are complex, and the content that is changing is not.

Comment: I am trying to picture your issue but it is less obvious than you think. Moar data please ?